# DocuSign Integration Into FileMaker

Tags: docusignapi, filemaker

The basic work-flow I am trying to implement is to generate a PDF from FileMaker data, upload it to DocuSign for signing, and download the signed document back to FileMaker.

The DocuSign API requires custom headers, so I cannot use the built-in FileMaker 13 *Insert From URL* script step. Instead, I am using the `BaseElements` plug-in `BE_HTTP_Set_Custom_Header` and `BE_GetURL` functions. I currently have the DocuSign Login API call working.

Now I am trying to use the DocuSign API to upload a document and request a signature. This requires a `multi-part/form-data` POST request. Unfortunately, neither the BaseElements nor Troi URL plug-ins support `multipart/form-data`. In fact, I cannot find any plug-in that does. **Is anyone aware of a FileMaker plug-in that supports `multipart/form-data` POST?**

https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/request-signatures

According to a comment on the Goya support forum last week, the next version of the BaseElements plug-in should support pass-through to the curl command line utility. If true, then as an alternative it seems possible to write a curl command to build the proper request, but my HTTP and curl knowledge is limited. So far, I have been unable to get the DocuSign signature request example working in Terminal. **Has anyone been able to upload a document and request a signature with a single curl command?**

http://support.goya.com.au/discussions/free-baseelements-plugin/1088-be-plugin-and-http-file-upload

**Finally, I would be grateful for any other ideas or suggestions for attacking this problem.**

Thank you!

Comment: I've not worked with DocuSign or with post requests that require `multi-part/form-data` so I can't give a for sure answer. Just thinking of possibilities, you may be able to send it via javascript (I'm thinking specifically jquery) from within a webviewer if jquery gives those options. I haven't thought out how you would do it exactly, but using javascript via the webviewer unlocks a lot more possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Yoo could use ScriptMaster and Groovy to write your own function to support the multipart/form-data type

Answer (score 0):

It took me a whole week but I managed to get it working on FileMaker 14.

It took me a whole week but I did manage to integrate it completely. I studied with my CEO the various providers out there and we ended up choosing DocuSign because our clients would be able to sign/approve our Estimates from literally any device (and also providing us with some more information if we need) such as Credit Card and etc), and because the annual costs were very competitive.

On the Development side it was hard, but not impossible.

The steps to master it are as follows:

1 - Study REST, and HTTP requests fundamentals (two youtube videos will do the trick).

2 - Get familiar with the command Curl in order to make  POST and GET requests from Terminal (on Mac). Once you get to this point. Then you can try to follow Docusign's steps to POST and GET from Mac Terminal (not through FileMaker as yet). The first command that worked for me is as follows:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H 'X-DocuSign-Authentication:{"Username": "myemail@hotmail.com","Password": "mypassword", "IntegratorKey": "fae5e715-dec2-477f-906e-b6300bc9d09a"}' -X GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/8aabdb38-41ab-4fab-bae9-63a071394a7a
```

If you replace the text above in bold with your DocuSign Developer credentials/information you should get a HTTP Header 200 OK - which means that you are in the right way.

This is important because you need to understand what information should be in the Headers, allowing Docusign to accept your requests.

3 - Translate the same concept into FileMaker. This is the most tricky part. First you need to create two Custom Variables. One will be your Docusign authentication (email, password and Integration Key). Something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGr61.png)

and the other one will be your endPoint , which is simply your Docusign url followed by your account number.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jP2Zk.png)

4 - Now you need to install BaseElements plugin onto your FileMaker Database(you wouldn't need this if you were using FileMaker 16). This will allow you to send POST, GET, DELETE, and UPDATE requests to Docusign. Unfortunately BaseElements's documentation is not super so I struggled a little bit till a get an actual result, but I will try to break it down for you here.

In order to make a GET request similar to the example that we have made we need to make a one line Script which looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h79Jy.png)

and then, inside the Refresh Object function:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSEXp.png)

This Script was adapted from a BaseElements plugin used to do Vimeo HTTP GET Requests - please see the link for more details on how to use it and test it: FileMaker REST using BaseElements Plugin - ISO FileMaker Magazine .

I think this gives you pretty much a good idea of how it works.

Unfortunately Docusign still doesn't provide any documentation or support to FileMaker developers, and this is as far as the internet goes. So if you need to make POST requests, it will get a bit more complex since you will have to put your FileMaker fields in JSON format, BaseElements POST syntax changing the script from GET to POST accordingly and POST inserting one more command with your data:

```
// insert this on your FileMaker POST script after the Headers List end

           ~data = BE_HTTP_POST ( ~endpoint ; "{
\"documents\": [ 
{ all of your JSON code adapted to FileMaker }]}");
```

You will also have to turn the PDF files that you want to send into Base64 format.

If you do this trick you will be good to go.